# Is P(Y = y) in the marginal probability formula always 1? Any special cases where P(Y = y) < 1?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, marginal-probability

The marginal probability equation follows:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{Y} P(X = x | Y = y)P(Y = y)
\end{equation}

Practically, it seems that most computations actually utilize the sum of the conditional probabilities rather than the sum of joint probabilities,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{Y} P(X = x | Y = y)
\end{equation}

Given my lack of knowledge in the probability domain, **is P(Y = y) always equal to 1, or are there any special cases where P(Y = y) would be less than 1?** (In which case, computation would be explicitly performed using the sum of the joint probabilities).

Comment: Your second expression involving joint probabilities is the marginal probability of $X=x$, assuming that $Y$ has a discrete distribution and the sum is actually over $y$ in its support. Using conditional probabilities $\sum\limits_{y} P(X = x \mid Y = y)P(Y = y)$ is also the  marginal probability of $X=x$. Your first expression is not anything obvious in general. $P(Y=y)=1$ can be true for a single value of $y$ iff $Y$ is almost surely $y$ and $P(Y \not=y)=0$

Comment: If the people you meet assume $P(Y=y)= 1$ then either 1. they are wrong or 2. they're stupid to even consider conditioning when $Y$ is almost surely $y$.

Answer (score 2):

For discrete random variables, $X,Y$, the **Law of Total Probability** states:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}x)~&=~\sum_y\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y)\\[2ex]&=~\sum_y\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y)~\mathsf P(Y{=}y)\end{align}$$

Note: the *conditional* probability $\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y)$ is not generally equal to the *joint* probability $\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y)$.   Indeed, the **definition for conditional probability** is that for discrete random variables (where $\{Y{=}y\}$ is not a zero measure event) we have:$$\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y)~=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y)}{\mathsf P(Y{=}y)}$$

Comment: Yes, apologies I mix a comma with a | in my question.

Comment: My point I am making is that in most situations involving discrete distributions we can compute the marginal probability following this equation when \begin{equation}
\sum_{Y} P(X = x | Y = y)
\end{equation}, which would mean P(Y = y) is thus 1. Is P(Y = y) always 1?

Comment: My point is that you *cannot* do that in *most* situations.